# Laptop black screen occasionally on start

Tags: laptop, battery, power

Sometimes when I start my laptop the screen does not turn on and stays blank/black and dark. It used to happen on rare occasions (couple of times a month max) but now it happens almost everyday and I have to force power down and restart up to 20 times before it works.

I have googled around but most suggestions say the screen is dead which is not the case as when it does start I can use it for hours on end with no issues. It has 16GB of RAM and 1x2.5" SSD and 1xmsata SSD. I thought it could be maybe a power issue so I removed one SSD and it made no difference. I've tried with and without AC adapter and also tried removing the battery and holding the power key.

Specifications:

- Dell e7440
- Intel i7
- 16GB RAM
- 2x SSD (1x 2.5" and 1x msata)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like the backlight  inverter is failing.

Comment: Look at the event log off your OS to determine if it's actually starting up. There may also be clues in there as to what's going on.

Comment: Ahh yeh perhaps, any idea of a easy way to confirm that? thanks

Comment: I'll see if my OS has event logs (not checked it before) if machine starts again - today has been particularly bad with starts

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Hey, nothing showing in event view for Ubuntu - also no sound in headphones that usually sound when changing volume and no output to ext monitor via hdmi (although auto connect monitor maybe a setting i've turned off)

Comment: So the machine isn't booting the OS. This may mean you have a bad motherboard, or possibly bad RAM.

Comment: Or flaky disk... to test, run OS from USB.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Tried with 1 RAM module and no change, tested with the other to and still similar behaviour. Really hope its not the motherboard. However why would it be intermittent, wouldn't hardware be good or bad not somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Could be I shall try that - however I doubt it as I have 2x SSD's and have tried with each one...

Comment: Hardware failure can manifest itself in erratic and intermittent behavior. It's not always black and white.

Answer (score 0):

While not a definitive answer in your particular case, but often times with laptops, the connection from the motherboard/GPU to the monitor is easily worn out and/or loosened. Though this can occur even through normal usage, its much more likely if the opening and closing of the lid has been a little rougher than average. I'm not insinuating this is the case in your situation, since even years of use or frequent use can be the culprit.

Again, this isn't necessarily the cause of your issue, and some would reason that if it were a hardware issue, it'd be more constant or permanent. I've opened up the guts of a few tablets and laptops, and can assure you, if the connection is somewhat loose, it won't necessarily be a constant issue.

If you'd find it helpful at all, I can provide photos of a laptop's internal architecture. Though I would not advise attempting to repair this problem yourself, I *have* simply fastened the connection back in place on a few tablets in the past, which resolved the display problems. Again, while not highly advisable, should you choose to attempt any type of disassembly, I'd implore you to check your manufacturer's documentation as most provide instructions in this process.

Comment: I've taken many laptops apart previously so it's definitely worth a shot. Could you send me the photos you speak of? Thanks

Comment: If its the monitor/gpu cable would that stop the OS loading? As it does not seem the OS is loading when the screen doesn't turn on...